# Force domain PC to sync time with another domain PC

Tags: command-line, sync, date-time

I thought this would force workstation 12, at 14:53 (time) to sync with whatever time was on workstation10.

```
at \\workstation12 14:53 net time \\workstation10 /set
```

When I execute the command, the response is "Added a new job with job ID = 1"... but the time never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workstations do not broadcast time sync data for other workstations to sync from. Since Win2000, all windows OS's have had a service that sync's time from one of the DC's in the domain. If the time offset is too large, the time sync service may not be able to correct the time difference - you would need to do that manually via the time & date control panel.

You can initiate a resync cycle with `w32tm /resync`
You can query offset between the workstation and the DC with `w32tm /query /status`
Other `W32TM` options can be found [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491016.aspx)

**Edit**
Remote resync `w32tm /resync /computer:workstation12`
May not work if time delta is > 5 min, because Kerberos auth observes time to prevent MITM attacks. In that case only remote option would be RDP with the local admin account.